# how to startx on remote machine in gnu/linux

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, xorg, vnc

I would like to `startx` on a remote machine, having the `X` session on that remote machine's display/monitor.

Background:
My machines all run Arch linux, and they all dont use a graphical login manager (like GDM or KDM or such). I usually log into tty, and type in "`startx`" to start my XFCE4 session.
While on work, I sometimes connect to my home-machine via VNC. This works nice.
Sometimes, I do stuff that requires my remote machine (at home) to reboot.

If I do so, there is no way to re-connect to the machine, as my VNC-connection needs a running X session (for `x11vnc` in my case).
So, I need a procedure to somehow connect to my freshly rebooted remote machine (to TTY1) in order to type in `username`, `password` and "`startx`".

Could someone please give a hint how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. However you can't startx remotely in the way you suggest. For x11vnc to work you need to have the Xserver running. I suggest you install xdm which will get you to a login screen in X. You can then have x11vnc on the Xserver and log in that way.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh -X ...` will enable X11 forwarding . But you need a support at the server side.

PS: I have newer tried to run whole xfce session through. So I am curious myself :D

Comment: thx for your time, but if I disconnect from that ssh session, the X session of my remote machine will quit, too... I would like to start the user X session at the remote machine tty1, not forward it via ssh...

Answer (score 0):

The problem ultimately stems from the `Xorg` binary no longer having setuid root permissions, and remote ssh does not get you the required permissions on a real `tty`.

You can work around this reasonably cleanly by editing/creating the file `/etc/X11/XWrapper.conf` and make sure to set:

```
allowed_users = anybody
```

See [Xorg.wrap(1)](https://man.linuxreviews.org/man1/Xorg.wrap.1.html). You will then be able to run `startx` over an SSH session.

This will run what ever Xorg you normally get while at a real screen
(no Xvfb or other hacks). I use the TigerVNC `libvnc.so` module loaded by Xorg so I can VNC directly with reasonable performance.

One final wrinkle: if you are using this to recover from power outages some driver/Xorg combinations will not start if they cannot determine
a resolution from a connected monitor (i.e. if there is no monitor or it's powered off). [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313076/31352) worked for me with an *Nvidia* video card:

```
Section "Device"
  ..
  Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "true"
EndSection
```

You may need to also set a Display with Virtual dimensions, or use `xrandr --fb WxH` to fix the resolution if it's not as expected.